# Unity won't load with proprietary drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia-optimus

First time running Ubuntu 11.04 and getting used to Unity, I decided to install proprietary drivers for my Nvidia graphic card.
The output of `lspci | grep VGA` is:

**00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor   Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0df5 (rev a1)**

If I activate the driver that is "recommended", next time I try to login in a Unity session it just changes to the classic.  How can that be happening?

I attach the screenshoot of my proprietary driver screen:

[image]

Comment: It would appear that you have two graphics cards: an integrated Intel one and an Nvidia one... although I'm not positive considering that it simply calls the Nvidia board a 'device'.

Comment: Yes I do have. But would that be the cause of the problem?

Comment: You may also need to change BIOS settings for the NVidia card (e.g. to be displayed first).

Comment: Does the order of the output of that command means which one is used as default?

Comment: This question has the best answers with optimus: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the bumblebee section in https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

```
b) try bumblebee for simultaneously using the intel and nvidia cards:
sudo apt-get install git
# type password
git clone http://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee.git
cd bumblebee/
sudo ./install.sh
optirun glxgears
# check the speed and compare to running:
glxgears
# If you have google-chrome installed, you can try it with/without optirun and report the FPS values on the mailing list:
optirun google-chrome http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html
```

Comment: I configured it and it seems to work fine.  Let's see when the automatic switching comes into action.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the bad support for intel sandy bridge graphics driver, infact what you have is not a pure nVidia graphics driver, it's an intel graphics with nVidia optimus tecnology.

The nVidia drivers doesn't work for me too.

Comment: Have a look at the bumblebee section in https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo get-apt remove nvidia-common
sudo get-apt remove nvidia-current
sudo get-apt remove nvidia-settings
sudo get-apt install nvidia-common
sudo get-apt install nvidia-current
sudo get-apt install nvidia-settings
```

Reboot and activate the new driver.

Comment: A more elegant way to do this with a single command is: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install nvidia-common nvidia-current nvidia-settings`